# fread weird behavior in c

Tags: c, buffer

I wrote a code just to understand how fread works and I don't understand how this is possible. Here my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    char spool[5] = "hello";
    fread(spool, sizeof(char), 6, stdin); //stdin == "bonjour"
    printf("\n%s\n", spool);
}
```

So first, I thought spool's value would be replaced by "bonjo" but I got "bonjou". I don't understand why I get a 6 characters string instead of a 5 characters string.

Comment: So you read six characters into an array that can contain only five characters? You need to read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Also remember that all strings must be *terminated*, if you don't add a terminator then you will have yet another case of UB (Undefined Behavior).

Comment: Aside: please note that `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition. And that `fread()` returns the number of bytes read - very useful.

Comment: In fact, my common sense tell me that normally when I try to put a 6 string into spool, I should get a compilation error, that's what happened when I ask for a 10 string.

Comment: @jehutyy The compiler cannot know in advance what you are going to type in run-time. And even if it somehow knew, it wouldn't prevent it. The main strength of C is freedom to do whatever you want, with very few restrictions. Which at the same time makes it easy to create bugs unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> char spool[5] = "hello";

This is wrong, because strings in C are null terminated. You don't allocate space for the null termination. A decent compiler should give you a warning about this. (Apparently gcc does not even with -Wall -Wextra, so that kind of sucks).

Reading "bounjour" into that array is also wrong, because C arrays have no boundary checks, nor do any of the library functions. So if you try to store more data in the array than you have room, you will write outside the boundaries of the array and the program will (hopefully) crash. You invoke undefined behavior, so anything might happen.

Solve this by declaring a large enough array, and study null termination of strings.

Comment: Wonder why this did not receive any vote (Sometimes SO stinks). That `hello` part was well noticed. Plus one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the size of the `spool` buffer, (it cannot store more than 5 `char`s,  that leads to Undefined beahvior):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char spool[15] = "hello";
    fread(spool, sizeof(char), 6, stdin); //stdin == "bonjour"
    printf("\n%s\n", spool);
}
```

Output:

```
bonjou
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is undefined behavior. You are trying to read 6 characters into a array which can hold 5 characters.Please note that the array should be large enough to hold a nul terminator.

Increase the size of your array `spool` to hold required characters.